# Generator non repeating numbers using PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to write simple page which will allow me to generate non-repeating numbers.

I have below code:

```
function rand ( min, max, except ) {
  var number = except;
  while (number == except) {
      number = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max + 1 - min ) + min );
  }
  return number;
}

var test = [];
while ( test.length < 1 ) {
  test.push( rand( 100, 500) ); 
}
alert( test );
```

It works fine, the only thing is that it will generate random number , but after I click for e.g. "Submit" button, it will generate new random numbers which can be same as when generated at previous request.

What I need is - page should somehow save already generated numbers and next time when it generates number, it shouldn't use it again.

Any ideas how to do that?

---

Maybe there is some function which creates random number based on time / date etc.

Comment: when you calll `rand()` you did not pass `except`. so what your rand() do?

Comment: You'll have to keep a record of the numbers already generated. A database, a file, something. Alternatively you can also pass in the max value of the previous generated number, start from there and set a new range of `max_num` to `larger_than_max`. Repeat until infinity.

Comment: @Andrew mySQL DB can be used. Can you seuggest the way how to achoeve it usinjg DB?

Comment: How long do you want to not-repeat previous numbers? Until the next navigation, the end of the browser session, the next year? For ever? (2) Should the memory be for each user separately or be a global memory?

Comment: @trincot - for ever

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
<?php

   function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity)
    {
       $numbers = range($min, $max);
       shuffle($numbers);
       return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
    }

    print_r(randomGen(0,20,20)); //generates 20 unique random numbers

?>
```